# Choose order Rails records, or show " ALL " in first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm searching for a method to choose the first record of a grouped_collection_select, or to show " ALL " in the first choice.

```
<%= f.collection_select :marque_id, Marque.all, :id, :name_upper, :include_blank => 'ALL', :prompt => 'Mark' %>         
     <%= f.grouped_collection_select :modele_id, Marque.all, :modeles, :name_upper, :id, :name_upper, :prompt => 'Model', :include_blank => 'ALL' %>
```

The " :include_blank => 'ALL' " work fine for the collection_select, but not for the grouped_collection_select.

For the grouped_collection_select, it only show a blank field at the first place.

I tried to put a blank record in the database, or to put " ALL " in the database with a lot of symbol like : " # ALL # " ... Didn't work with number ( 147, 156, 159 [...], # ALL #,...)

EDIT:

Or maybe I can add a field in each subcategories, and define that "First" ? But I want to keep everything ordering by "name ASC".

I already put

```
    default_scope order('name ASC')
```

in my Modele.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do what I wanted.

I just had to add

```
$('#search_modele_id').preprend('<option value="" selected="selected">ALL</option>');
```

to my jQuery code, and put the value as " BLANK " (really important in my case).

And put

```
:include_blank => true
```

Instead of

```
:include_blank => 'ALL'
```

In the search form

Problem solved.

Thanks anyway!